# Пожалуйста объясните как работает код (код на С#)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int r = Mul2(40, 54);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static int Mul2(int someInt, int someInt2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method has become to work");
            Console.WriteLine(someInt);
            Console.WriteLine(someInt2);
            int Result = (someInt * someInt2);
            Result = Result * Result;
            return Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Method end!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Как происходит присваивание переменных, обработка самого кода от начала до конца программы (просто я недавно в С#).

Comment: @user7130621: Вам, очевидно, сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105

Comment: Присваивание происходит при помощи операции `=`. Обработка кода идёт построчно.

Comment: someInt получило значение 40, someInt2 инициализировалось как 54.
Затем вы подсчитали result путем перемножения 40 и 54, затем перемножили result само на себя и функция вернула это значение, которая получила переменная r в Main.

Answer (score 2):

В методе **main**:
1)Переменной **r** вы возвращаете результат работы метода *Mul2*.

2)Ничего не записываете на консоль методом *Console.WriteLine()*;

3)Ожидаете ввода строки.

В методе **Mul2**:

1)Сообщается, что метод начал работу, выводится на экран первый и второй параметры; 
2)В новую переменную *Result* записываем перемножение первого и второго числа;
3)Дальше *Result* присваивается перемножение самой на себя; 
4)Возвращаем значения переменной *Result*.

Выскакивает ошибка (или предупреждение?), что-то похожее на *statement not reachable*

Ошибка (или предупреждение?) из-за того, что метод завершил уже свою работу (оператор **return** "завершает" работу метода), а вы пытаетесь еще что-то там делать (в данном случае написать в консоль, что метод завершил работу).

Дабы метод заработал и строка *Console.WriteLine()* стала **"досягаемой"** поднимите ее просто **над** оператором **return**.

Comment: 2)Ничего не записываете на консоль методом Console.WriteLine(); - а как-же возврат каретки ? :-)

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin, ая-я-яй)) Подловил, молодец !)

Answer (score 1):

Запускается программа и автоматически вызывается метод `Main`, который объявляет целочисленную переменную `r` и присваивает ей результат работы метода `Mul2`.
Т.е. из `Main` вызываем `Mul2` с параметрами 40 и 54, и результат записываем в переменную `r`. 
При вызове метода `Mul2`выводится сообщение что начали работать, выводим первую переданную переменную (40) и вторую (54).

В целочисленную переменную `Result` записываем произведение 40 х 54 (3780).

После этого в переменную `Result` записываем предыдущее значение этой же переменной, умноженное само на себя (возводим в квадрат).
Т.е. `Result` будет равен `Result = 3780 х 3780 = 14288400`.

Теперь из метода `Mul2` возвращаем значение это 14288400 в вызвавший его метод 'Main' где значение 14288400 присваевается переменной `r`.

Теперь выводим пустую строку, и жмем нажатия Enter. Завершаем работу программы.

Вывод строки "Method end!" выполнен не будет, так как команда для вывода этого текста написана после оператора `return`, который мало того, что возвращает результат в метод `Main`, так еще и завершит работу метода 'Mul2'.

Answer (score 0):

someInt получило значение 40, someInt2 - 54.
Затем вы подсчитали result путем перемножения 40 и 54, затем перемножили result само на себя и функция вернула это значение, которая получила переменная r в Main.

Comment: И еще: строка "Console.WriteLine("Method end!");" - не досягаема. Функция вернула новый Result.

Comment: А почему строка "Console.WriteLine("Method end!");" - не досягаема?

Comment: @user7130621, потому что после выполнения return функция покидается

Comment: Спасибо всем вам.